# Frozen webview when clicking textbox in embedded web - Android 4.3

Tags: android, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I try to run an embedded web in Android, but it crashes when using Android 4.3 (Nexus 4). I run the app and the first webview appears correctly, but when I touch the textbox and the keyboard appears, the view gets frozen just on the top part of the keyboard (where the text predictor is located in case it's active).

This problem only appeared when using 4.3, not with the previous versions.

I've been trying to fix the bug as it says in this issue, but the solutions they give don't resolve my case: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42518&q=webview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

I would love if somebody have been through this problem, because we don't know what to do to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than one year without trying the app, it is working now. The device now is running Android Lollipop, so I guess that probably the WebView has some improvement that avoids the bug.